# Flutter how to save(re-encode) text overlay on video

Tags: flutter, overlay, encode

I would like to implement feature like instagram story(only text overlay).
I was able to come to the point where user can add some text on video like screen shot below(upper right icon starts entering text, upper left just back to previous page).
After user put some text I want store the video into `Firebase storage`.
But the problem is how can I keep this text in the video?
Is there any way to rewrite the file(re-encode) which has text overlay user put?
Or do I have to store text info into database then fetch it and display every time?

[image]

Comment: the easy way as you said is to store the text in firestore and fetch when you need, otherwise you will need work with native code to manipulate the video.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Ok I will go for that but one thing concerns me is that device size is different each other. For example, userA put text from Iphone x, and userB see the video from Iphone SE, and userA put text very bottom, since SE is much smaller than X, userB might not be able to see it am I right? How can I make it responsive? Do you have any idea?

Comment: check my answer here using LayoutBuilder : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786364/how-to-use-mediaquery-to-set-scalefactor-for-text-in-flutter/51796799#51796799

Comment: Thank you I will check that. Also, is there any possibility that flutter support the re-encode the video future?

Comment: using platform channels it should be possible

Comment: @Daibaku Have you got the solution for this. Because of I ant to the same thing but didn't get any solution. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not a complete answer as I believe you will have to work a bit yourself to get it working.

So, I am facing a similar scenario where I need to add some overlay stuff to a video recorded.

I came across this package https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg

If you look into some information about ffmpeg, you'll find that it includes some video and audio manipulation tools.

I have yet to try it but I will begin soon and update you with any methods.
If possible, I'll probably write a package for it, so that overlay can be added to videos easily.

If you find something else, let me know

Comment: Hi @Jose Tapizquent I also want to add a text watermark on a video using flutter. Did you find any method? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Jose Tapizquent, I'm working on watermark & text on videos, do you have any results?

Comment: Were you able to add a watermark to a video using this package?

Answer (score 3):

There is a pub (https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca) but it is very limited in capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I can only give a partial answer, I hope it helps anyway.

You can use a `PictureRecorder` to export a bitmap or png of a `Canvas` in Flutter.

The png image should have the same size as the source video, and you can overlay it over the video with a simple `Image` widget.

You can also upload this png image to Firebase, then download it on other clients to get exactly the same appearance (even when fonts are not installed).

The cool thing is that you can even save things like hand drawings, stickers, gradients and complex shapes (everything you can draw on a canvas) in the png image.

I guess you could also use some kind native library to bake the png image into the video if that is a requirement.

Here is a simple example to show how to generate and display such a png image:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// @param size Video size
/// @param text Styled text
ui.Image createTextImage(Size size, TextSpan text) {
  final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final cullRect = Offset.zero & size;
  final canvas = Canvas(recorder, cullRect);

  final textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, text: text);
  textPainter.layout();

  // draw text in center of canvas, you can adjust this as you like
  final textOffset = cullRect.center.translate(-textPainter.width / 2, textPainter.height / 2);
  textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);

  // you can also draw other geometrical shapes, gradients, paths...
  canvas.drawCircle(Offset(100.0, 100.0), 50.0, Paint()..color = Color(0xffff00ff));

  final picture = recorder.endRecording();
  final image = picture.toImage(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());

  return image;
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Canvas Test',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  /// Bytes of the generated image
  Future<Uint8List> _imageBytes;

  _generateImage() {
    // Get this size from your video
    final videoSize = Size(720.0, 1280.0);

    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      fontSize: 80.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
    final text = TextSpan(text: 'Hello World', style: textStyle);

    // Generate the image
    final imageInfo = createTextImage(videoSize, text);

    // Convert to png
    final imageBytes =
        imageInfo.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png).then((byteData) => Uint8List.view(byteData.buffer));

    setState(() {
      _imageBytes = imageBytes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Canvas Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _imageBytes,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('No data');

                // Display the generated image in a box
                return DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                  child: Image.memory(
                    snapshot.data,
                    width: 180.0,
                    height: 320.0,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: _generateImage, child: Text('Generate Image'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer but I don't think I understand that correctly. What you are saying is about image?  If I want encode video, I have to write native code as well?

Comment: Very likely. There is no video manipulation library for dart. Did you think about using a backend service for the video manipulation?

Comment: Now I understand thank you boformer. No I didn’t is there something you recommend? What I’m planning is let user capture video and after that store into firebase.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854506/how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-video-in-android-java