# Adding custom frame to an image in flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to know how can i add frame to a photo.i am trying to make a photo frame app where user will pick photo from gallery and can be able to add frame to the picture.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please do some google searches and try to create something before you ask a question. In your question, tell us exactly what you have tried (with example code), and what specific problem you are experiencing.

Comment: thanks for your reply I want to know how can I put two image in a canvas one is front and the other is back.. the  front image will be treated like a frame..the concept is to put one layer to another..I am not sure I can explain it or not but if you know something about my topic then please help me..thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this answer how to overlay text over a video. It's not completely what you are looking for, but shows how to create a canvas, how to draw stuff on it, then convert it to a png format (converting to jpg would be better in your case). You can use `canvas.drawImageRect` to draw your photo on the canvas before you draw the frame (which could also be an image, or some other shape):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852673/flutter-how-to-savere-encode-text-overlay-on-video/51866890#51866890

Comment: thanks for your feedback.I will look forward it.

Comment: have you solved this

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it's what you're looking for but I think you could use this plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Instead of taking a photo, select the image gallery

Comment: yeah I know about it but I want to add another bitmap frame to an image..