# Video Editor in Flutter using dart

Tags: android, ios, plugins, dart, flutter

I am looking for a plugin or example of a video editor in flutter using dart.

I have tried the following plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player, but it doesn't seems to have properties that I can edit the video. Example trim or add a watermark on the video.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: If you can deal with something very low level then https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg is there.

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this Flutter package called [video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer). This package is developed by me, it helps in trimming videos in most of the commonly used formats. You can also generate GIFs from the videos.

This also provides a nice **UI** for trimming videos.

The package is currently in **beta** stage. So, feel free to make a PR on the [GitHub](https://github.com/sbis04/video_trimmer) repo of this package, if you have any suggestions for improvement.

Currently, it doesn't have the feature to add a watermark to any video.

Answer (score 4):

- Comments mentioned https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg, though I couldn’t find anything that explicitly documents a way to edit the video, such as a watermark. But it should be possible according to others https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847155/6668797.
- There’s also https://pub.dev/packages/video_manipulation

  > Adding still frames to an existing video, e.g. watermarks
  >
  > `.generateVideo(List<String> paths, String filename, int fps, double
  >   speed).`
  >
  > Parameters `paths` list of input file paths. Can be images (.jpg or
  >   .png) or video files (.mp4) that are used to generate the new video.
  >   E.g.: `["documents/input.mp4", "documents/watermark.jpg]`

Otherwise, there’s currently not much in readily available packages for video editing for Flutter as I couldn't find anymore at https://pub.dev/flutter. For more options, you’ll have to seek out native Android/iOS libraries and [custom integrate them through the platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).