# How to add watermark on image while reading it from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, firebase, watermark

I am working on a React website where I want to add watermark on an image when user reads that image from Firebase storage. So is there any way to add watermark while reading the image from the storage ?

I've already gone through [How to add an image or text (Watermark) on a video/image - Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729010/how-to-add-an-image-or-text-watermark-on-a-video-image-flutter-dart) but it's related to Flutter/Dart, but I want the answer for REACT.

Kindly guide me through this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried stack widget?

Comment: That's related to flutter and I want for web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a watermark to images in to Firebase Storage, I'd typically do that using a Cloud Function that triggers when the image is uploaded. You can base it on the example image converter here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/convert-images

The sample uses Image Magick to perform the conversion, so you can also use [Image Magick to add a watermark](https://www.google.com/search?q=imagemagick+add+watermark) to the image.

Comment: That GitHub link you shared is just converting the image extension.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said. But it shows how to call Image Magick in a Cloud Function. The second link them shows a way that Image Magick can be used to add a watermark to an image. You'll have to combine the two steps into a single solution yourself.