# How can i merge widget into image or video

Tags: flutter, dart

i am displaying image in my `UI` using `mage.network` widget, and display `Text` widget in `Stack`
like following

```
  Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.network('myImage'),
        Text('Hello world')
      ],
    );
```

also the same idea but with video

```
 Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        VideoPlayer('myVideoFile'),
        Text('Hello world')
      ],
    );
```

**now my question** : How can i merge ANY `Widget` that add into `stack` `(in my case Text('Hello world'))` into one final result file ?

`in other word` : if i want to save my image or video into my storage so Of course they will be saved separately from the widgets they have inside `Stack` . but How could i merge the widgets with them and became one file? so when i save them to my storage and want to open them again i will find the `widgets` already merged with them

the only way i have now is to screenshot my screen using `screenshot` plugin and save the result as one file . and the same with video but with `record_screen plugin` But it is a very bad experience

What should I look for to handle this work?
any plugin ?
Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729010/how-to-add-an-image-or-text-watermark-on-a-video-image-flutter-dart

Comment: thanks , they all were useless and old