# Add watermark to image/video taken from flutter camera

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a live streaming app out of flutter and I am live streaming video captured from camera and I want to add water mark on video. So basically what I want is to integrate watermark on Camera.

Comment: Is this helpful ? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729010/how-to-add-an-image-or-text-watermark-on-a-video-image-flutter-dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an image or text (Watermark) on a video/image - Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729010/how-to-add-an-image-or-text-watermark-on-a-video-image-flutter-dart)